# Calendar Input with Php

Tags: php

I have a problem that I don't quite understand how to solve, and I came here to see if you can help me.
The thing is that I have the calendar of 
and I need to block intermediate dates
example of this would be:
dates from 2022/11/01 to 2022/11/10 and I have to discard the dates from 2022/11/02 to 2022/11/05 and 2022/11/07 to 2022/11/09
and what it should show is in a single input the remaining dates
I mean the dates
2022/11/01,2022/11/06,2022/11/10

```
<?php
    $reservSQL = new ReservSQL();
    $reservList = $reservSQL->GetReservbyIdKeeper($idKeeper);
    if ($reservList == null) {
    ?>
        <td>
           <input type="date" name="dateStart" min="<?php echo $keeper->getTypeUserKeeper()->getDateStart(); ?>" max="<?php echo $keeper->getTypeUserKeeper()->getDateFinish(); ?>" placeholder="START" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" name="dateFinish" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($keeper->getTypeUserKeeper()->getDateStart() . "+1 day")); ?>" max="<?php echo $keeper->getTypeUserKeeper()->getDateFinish(); ?>" placeholder="FINISH" required>
        </td>
           <?php
            }
             elseif($reservList!=null){
                 $reserv=new Reserv();
                 foreach ($reservList as $reserv) {}
                 ?>
                 <tbody>
                    <td>
                       <input type="date" name="dateStart" 
                              min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($reserv->getDateFinish() . "+1 day")); ?>" 
                              max="<?php echo $keeper->getTypeUserKeeper()->getDateFinish(); ?>"
placeholder="START" required>
                    </td>    
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" name="dateFinish" 
                               min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($reserv->getDateFinish() . "+1 day")); ?>" 
                               max="<?php echo $keeper->getTypeUserKeeper()->getDateFinish(); ?>" placeholder="FINISH" required>
                    </td>
                         </tbody>
           <?php                 
            }
           ?>
```

The thing is that I receive 2 date arrays and I try to get the dates that are reserved using min and max, it gets complicated because it reaches a point where the logic does not do what I want.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: "The thing is that I receive 2 date arrays"  Why 2?  Do they contain all the dates you want to discard, or just the start and the end?   Also why are you mixing logic with output? Just writing a function that does do what you want seems to be easier. It should not be hard to  output a list of the dates which are returned from that function.

Answer (score 0):

I know, I should put more time in programming in PHP, so please find a way to improve this (incomplete) code:

```
$dates = ['2022/11/01','2022/11/02','2022/11/03','2022/11/04','2022/11/05','2022/11/06','2022/11/07','2022/11/08','2022/11/09','2022/11/10'];

$skip1 = ['2022/11/02','2022/11/05'];
$skip2 = ['2022/11/07','2022/11/09'];

$i = new DateInterval("P1D");
$d = $skip1[0];
while ($d<=$skip1[1]) {
    $a=array_search($d,$dates);
    unset($dates[$a]);
    $t = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d', $d);
    print $t->format('Y/m/d')."\n";
    date_add($t,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
    $d = date_format($t,"Y/m/d");
}

var_dump($dates);
```

When `$skip1` contain a start- and end-date, this code will delete that range from `$dates`.  The output:

```
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  string(10) "2022/11/01"
  [5] =>
  string(10) "2022/11/06"
  [6] =>
  string(10) "2022/11/07"
  [7] =>
  string(10) "2022/11/08"
  [8] =>
  string(10) "2022/11/09"
  [9] =>
  string(10) "2022/11/10"
}
```

The code should be improved to repeat the step using `$skip2`, and from the code you will see that I am NOT experienced in PHP.